# RStudio - "Close All Except Current" Greyed Out

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm running RStudio 1.3.959 on a Windows 10 PC.

The "Close All Except Current" option under the "File" menu is greyed out. Does anyone know why this has happened and if there's a way to fix it please?

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps, you have only one open tab?

Comment: Thanks but I'm afraid not - I had about 10 tabs open at the time.